# chernoff bound application

Tags: analysis, probability-theory, statistics

say we sample a finite set a finite number of times (ie we have finitely many iid random variables $X_1,...,X_k$ taking values in a finite set).  i read that the [multiplicative chernoff bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound#Multiplicative_form_(relative_error)) can be used to upper bound the probability that more than n points are sampled (i.e. that $|\{X_1(\omega),...,X_k(\omega)\}|>n$).  could someone please explain how this works?

Even just indicating what the $X_i$ in the statement of the Chernoff bound are supposed to be in this case would be helpful.

Here is some context:  this is claimed in the book *Foundations of Machine Learning* (Mohri, Rostamizaeh, Talwalker) at the end of the proof of Theorem 3.6 which is giving lower bounds for generalization error in terms of VC dimension. [image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Recall that in this case they're studying a distribution that has mass $1-8\varepsilon$ on just one point, $x_0$. So, the probability of seeing at least $(d-1)/2$ distinct points is bounded by the probability that you saw at most $(d-1)/2$ points that are not $x_0$. The Chernoff bound is looking at this second event - the probability that you see at least $8\varepsilon m (1+\gamma)$ points that are not $x_0$ is bounded as in the question, and then appropriately choosing $\varepsilon$ does the job.

Comment: Also, btw, you should include the edition of a book you're citing. For instance, I have the second edition of this book, in which this theorem is numbered 3.20

Comment: @stochasticboy321 thanks for your help.  in your second sentence did you mean "...at *least* (d-1)/2 points that are not x_0"

Comment: and did you mean to omit "distinct" from what i quoted?

Comment: (completely as an aside, it is puzzling that gamma does not appear on the left hand side of 3.39, so that, taken literally, 3.39 implies that the LHS is zero...)

Comment: @bart I did mean to write at least, yes, thanks. And yes, I did mean to omit distinct there (you could keep distinct, but that's harder to bound. Droppind distinct, of course, still makes it an upper bound. Also, yeah, things are a little sloppy here - I didn't really spot why there's an equality in 3.39, it probably should be $\le$, and one needs $\gamma \le 1$ for the particular choice of $\varepsilon$ to get a bound on seeing more than $(d-1)/2$ other things. But the mechanics+idea of the proof are simple enough to fix the argument.

Comment: (Although with how sloppy I'm being in my explanations, maybe I don't really get to call folks out :P)

Comment: (also interesting that the probability of getting $(d-1)/2$ distinct points is supposed to go *down* as the number of samples taken (m) *increases*)

Comment: @stochasticboy321 thanks again. i guess i still don't understand how Chernoff's bound is being applied though

Comment: ^No, not really. $m$ interacts with the $\varepsilon$, right? As in $m$ is bounded as $O(d/\varepsilon),$ so while the bound goes to $0$ as $m$ increases, that's not a valid application of the bound.

Comment: @stochasticboy321  just so i at least understand your initial comment, it should be "So, the probability of seeing at least (−1)/2 distinct points is bounded by the probability that you saw at least [(−1)/2]-1 points that are not $x_0$."  is that correct? and then the -1 maybe doesn't matter in the limit or something?

Comment: @bart This is getting too long for the comments. Let me look more closely at the text and then write an answer.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 sure. again, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Getting too long for the comments)

---

The mechanics of the proof being studied here are as follows - $m, d$ are fixed numbers. $\mathbb{P}$ is such that for some point $x_0,$ $\mathbb{P}(x_0) = 1 - 8 \varepsilon$, where $\varepsilon$ is a quantity we can choose.

The rest of the proof shows that if for a given choice of $\varepsilon$, in a sample of $m$ trials, the probability of observing more than $(d-1)/2$ distinct points other than $x_0$ were to be smaller than some fixed number (say $ e^{-1/12}$) then 'risk' would be more than $\varepsilon$ (where 'risk' has some meaning pertinent to the text, let's ignore it).

Overall, our goal is to find the biggest $\varepsilon$ such that the above probability is constrained to be at most $1/100$. We will not actually find the biggest, but we'll find a 'big enough' value.

Now, the probability of seeing more than $(d-1)/2$ distinct points other than $x_0$ is itself bounded by the probability of not seeing $x_0$ at least $(d-1)/2$ times. Since the trials are iid, and the probability of seeing $x_0$ at is $1-8\varepsilon,$ we know, via the Chernoff bound, that the probability of not seeing $x_0$ at least $\varepsilon(1 + \gamma) m$ times is bounded as $\exp(-m\varepsilon \gamma^2/3)$.

At this point let's again carefully look at what's known, and what we want. $d, m$ are not in our control. $\varepsilon, \gamma$ are. We want to upper bound $$ \mathbb{P}(\textrm{At least $(d-1)/2$ points other than $x_0$ are in a sample of size $m$})$$

We have a unrelated statement saying that for any $\gamma > 0$, $$\mathbb{P}(\textrm{At least $8\varepsilon m(1 + \gamma)$ points other than $x_0$ are seen}) \le e^{-m\varepsilon \gamma^2/3}$$

Can we use the second bound to control the first to be smaller than $e^{-1/12}$? Yes, if $\varepsilon m (1+\gamma)$ were to equal $(d-1)/2$ (or something smaller, but remember that we want big $\varepsilon$ and $m$ is fixed), *and* if $m\varepsilon \gamma^2$ were to be large enough. This can further be attained by choosing $\varepsilon, \gamma$ as in the text (3.40). So, the whole setup works with this value of $\varepsilon.$ Ergo, the 'risk' is more than $\frac{(d-1)}{32 m}$.

The Chernof bound is being used in a roundabout way that is not very well explained in the text, IMO. It's role is to give some generic control for any value of $\varepsilon.$ We can then use this to find *one* value of $\varepsilon$ where 'nice' things happen.

Strictly speaking I'm being sloppy in the above - the measure $\mathbb{P}$ depends on $\varepsilon,$ so I should be writing something like $\mathbb{P}_{\varepsilon}$ above. Maybe this would further clarify things? There may also be some off-by-one errors somewhere in the above, but these have little bearing.

Comment: makes sense! wow that is *profoundly* under explained in the text.

Comment: @bart Yeah. And I've referred to foks to this proof *twice* in my papers! Rethinking that now... :-/